# Assign left mouse click to a keyboard key

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I would like to be able to assign a key on my keyboard to be equivalent to a left mouse click.

Ideally it needs to act such that holding the key down is also equivalent to holding the left mouse button down.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm almost positive you need to buy a new mouse. =P

Comment: OS X has limited options for simulating mouse clicks (applescript falls short in this department), but this might help you with the mouse click part: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008051406323031  --- After you edit it to your needs and compile, you'll need to bind that app to a hotkey in order to have a key press activate it, you can try something like Spark for that: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14352/spark -- not sure about the holding the key down though

Comment: In your [Stack Overflow duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312480/osx-assign-left-mouse-click-to-a-keyboard-key), you said you could also use a programmatic solution using AppleScript or Cocoa. Why not here?

Comment: slhck - I didn't mention programmatic solution here because I was treating SuperUser as a user focused site.  To be clear though - I am happy with a programmatic solution!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve this using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/). It's an app you'd have to install but it's free an has lots of other useful features. You can also choose to limit this functionality to a single application or use it globally.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In "Preferences" - "Keyboard" - "Add new shortcut", and in actions, select "leftclick".

Comment: slhck -  I couldn't get this to work

Answer (score 3):

You can use OS X's Mouse Keys feature to use the keyboard to click the mouse. (It's an accessibility feature.) You can enable a keyboard shortcut to turn it on and off if you don't want to use the feature all the time.

With Mouse Keys, just use the number 5 (or the equivalent letter key I) to click. Pressing 0 or M will work for holding down the mouse button, and period will release.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434#mousekeys

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to figure this out in 2017, then as Stacey Hanson wrote, OS X's Mouse Keys feature is a great way to go. From my playing around with it in masOS Sierra, the number 5 button on my numeric keyboard seems to work EXACTLY like the left mouse button does. I can hold it down and rotate the globe in Google maps satellite view - super helpful. Here's an updated link for accessing the feature: http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/input-devices/what-are-mouse-keys/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in macOS Sierra 10.12.6 using Karabiner Elements 11.6.0.

I remapped my Macbook function key to left click:

Under "Simple Modifications"
From Key: fn (under "Modifier keys")
To key: button1 (under "Mouse buttons")